# Create a tag for EdXposed

Tags: discussion, tags

[xposed-framework](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xposed-framework) is de facto dead , the last update being more than two years ago and that too for Oreo and there is no news of further updates.

EdXposed may be a preferred alternative being open source and having support from developer community.

I propose that a new tag [edxposed](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edxposed) be created . Creating a new tag, rather than making it a synonym for [exposed-framework](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exposed-framework) is perhaps a right choice since:

- Xposed supports upto Oreo while EdXPosed supports from Oreo to Android 10.
- Development on Xposed framework is dead while Edxposed (though in beta) is  avid.

If approved, these questions are to be re-tagged :

- [What are the alternatives for Xposed framework on Pie? Preferably without triggering Safety Net?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/207633/131553)
- [How to install EdXposed on Android 10 without triggering safety net](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218179/131553)
- [How to prevent apps from entering immersive mode in portrait mode?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/210593/131553)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing the upvotes to mean concurrence, I have created tag [edxposed](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edxposed) and re-tagged  the questions